# Position of an element in {}

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list, say {1,2,3,4}. Using extract I got {4}. Now, I want to know the position of 4 in the list.

To do that I would need to write Position[{1,2,3,4}, 4]. But I only have {4} (because I got it from Extract) So, what I can do is Position[{1,2,3,4}, {4}], but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you tried using First@, or {}[[1]]? It gets the first (and in your case the only) element of the list. So if you got {4} from extract, you can use First@{4}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Position[{4, 3, 2, 1}, 4]
```

or

```
Position[{4, 3, 2, 1}, {4}[[1]]]
```

or

```
Position[{4, 3, 2, 1}, First@{4}]
```

(* {{1}} *)

or

```
{4, 3, 2, 1}[[{4}]]
```

(* {1} *)

Comment: Thanks a lot David Stork. It works indeed :).